# .forEach is not a function. Not understanding why

Tags: javascript, json, function, api

I am doing an API project and I cannot for the life of me get past this error. The API dataset is from here: https://rapidapi.com/theapiguy/api/free-nba/

From what I've read I know it's got something to do with the fact than array is not being met, but I've tried object.keys and object.value and nothing has helped me get past the error.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```js
const app = {};


const $teamDropDown = ("$teamDropDown");
const $playerDropDown = ("$playerDropDown");

// need a function to populate teams dropdown 

app.populateTeamDropDown = () => {
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://free-nba.p.rapidapi.com/teams',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'f8bbeecee3mshd11af53a602b7fcp133f59jsn3b4ffb3f20df',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'free-nba.p.rapidapi.com'}

  }).then( (response) => { 
    
    response.forEach (teamObject) => {
      const teamName = teamObject.full_name;
      
    }
  
      
  });
}

app.init = () => {
  app.populateTeamDropDown();
}

$(function() {
  app.init();
});
```

**Sample response:**

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "abbreviation": "ATL",
      "city": "Atlanta",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Southeast",
      "full_name": "Atlanta Hawks",
      "name": "Hawks"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "abbreviation": "BOS",
      "city": "Boston",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Atlantic",
      "full_name": "Boston Celtics",
      "name": "Celtics"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "abbreviation": "BKN",
      "city": "Brooklyn",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Atlantic",
      "full_name": "Brooklyn Nets",
      "name": "Nets"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "abbreviation": "CHA",
      "city": "Charlotte",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Southeast",
      "full_name": "Charlotte Hornets",
      "name": "Hornets"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "abbreviation": "CHI",
      "city": "Chicago",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Central",
      "full_name": "Chicago Bulls",
      "name": "Bulls"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "abbreviation": "CLE",
      "city": "Cleveland",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Central",
      "full_name": "Cleveland Cavaliers",
      "name": "Cavaliers"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "abbreviation": "DAL",
      "city": "Dallas",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Southwest",
      "full_name": "Dallas Mavericks",
      "name": "Mavericks"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "abbreviation": "DEN",
      "city": "Denver",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Northwest",
      "full_name": "Denver Nuggets",
      "name": "Nuggets"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "abbreviation": "DET",
      "city": "Detroit",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Central",
      "full_name": "Detroit Pistons",
      "name": "Pistons"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "abbreviation": "GSW",
      "city": "Golden State",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "Golden State Warriors",
      "name": "Warriors"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "abbreviation": "HOU",
      "city": "Houston",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Southwest",
      "full_name": "Houston Rockets",
      "name": "Rockets"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "abbreviation": "IND",
      "city": "Indiana",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Central",
      "full_name": "Indiana Pacers",
      "name": "Pacers"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "abbreviation": "LAC",
      "city": "LA",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "LA Clippers",
      "name": "Clippers"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "abbreviation": "LAL",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "Los Angeles Lakers",
      "name": "Lakers"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "abbreviation": "MEM",
      "city": "Memphis",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Southwest",
      "full_name": "Memphis Grizzlies",
      "name": "Grizzlies"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "abbreviation": "MIA",
      "city": "Miami",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Southeast",
      "full_name": "Miami Heat",
      "name": "Heat"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "abbreviation": "MIL",
      "city": "Milwaukee",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Central",
      "full_name": "Milwaukee Bucks",
      "name": "Bucks"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "abbreviation": "MIN",
      "city": "Minnesota",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Northwest",
      "full_name": "Minnesota Timberwolves",
      "name": "Timberwolves"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "abbreviation": "NOP",
      "city": "New Orleans",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Southwest",
      "full_name": "New Orleans Pelicans",
      "name": "Pelicans"
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "abbreviation": "NYK",
      "city": "New York",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Atlantic",
      "full_name": "New York Knicks",
      "name": "Knicks"
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "abbreviation": "OKC",
      "city": "Oklahoma City",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Northwest",
      "full_name": "Oklahoma City Thunder",
      "name": "Thunder"
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "abbreviation": "ORL",
      "city": "Orlando",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Southeast",
      "full_name": "Orlando Magic",
      "name": "Magic"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "abbreviation": "PHI",
      "city": "Philadelphia",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Atlantic",
      "full_name": "Philadelphia 76ers",
      "name": "76ers"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "abbreviation": "PHX",
      "city": "Phoenix",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "Phoenix Suns",
      "name": "Suns"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "abbreviation": "POR",
      "city": "Portland",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Northwest",
      "full_name": "Portland Trail Blazers",
      "name": "Trail Blazers"
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "abbreviation": "SAC",
      "city": "Sacramento",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Pacific",
      "full_name": "Sacramento Kings",
      "name": "Kings"
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "abbreviation": "SAS",
      "city": "San Antonio",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Southwest",
      "full_name": "San Antonio Spurs",
      "name": "Spurs"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "abbreviation": "TOR",
      "city": "Toronto",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Atlantic",
      "full_name": "Toronto Raptors",
      "name": "Raptors"
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "abbreviation": "UTA",
      "city": "Utah",
      "conference": "West",
      "division": "Northwest",
      "full_name": "Utah Jazz",
      "name": "Jazz"
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "abbreviation": "WAS",
      "city": "Washington",
      "conference": "East",
      "division": "Southeast",
      "full_name": "Washington Wizards",
      "name": "Wizards"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total_pages": 1,
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page": null,
    "per_page": 30,
    "total_count": 30
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to show your response object json. How do we know what is inside?

Comment: @Serge The API keys currently work. I edited the question to include a sample response. (If you run the snippet in my answer, you can see a live response, as long as the API keys hold out)

Comment: Thanks. Not everybody is happy to click a stranger's web link.  For the future you don't need to show all that repeating items inside of json. A couple would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `response.data`

`response` is an object that contains the attributes `data` and `meta`.

`response.data` is an array of the data you requested.

Thus, you need to do `response.data.forEach()` instead of `response.forEach()`

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'https://free-nba.p.rapidapi.com/teams',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'f8bbeecee3mshd11af53a602b7fcp133f59jsn3b4ffb3f20df',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'free-nba.p.rapidapi.com'
  }

}).then((response) => {

  console.log(response);
  
  response.data.forEach((teamObject) => {
    const teamName = teamObject.full_name;
    console.log(teamName);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```